# Can Windows filesystem files show different size after being copied on a linux filesystem?

Tags: usb, filesystem

I copied a folder containing other subfolders, with some thousands of text files inside, from a FAT32 usb drive to the desktop of ubuntu.

After doing this, I checked the folder properties, to be sure I've correctly copied all, and I see that the two windows presents the same number of files, but have a difference of 88KB ?

Can this be due to the filesystem change ? My concern is about the reliability of the copy. Any ideas is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the discrepancy could be due to block size and other file system overhead. Linux (EXT) uses less fragmentation overhead, and a more compact disk structure so most of the times it will result in smaller files.

The easiest tool to compare files is `diff` if all you want to know if a file is the same.

```
diff file1 file2
```

It will tell you if files are identical and show nothing when there is no difference.

Example:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more 1
1
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more 2
1 
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ diff 1 2
```

and

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more 1
1
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more 2
2
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ diff 1 2
1c1
< 1 
---
> 2
```

You can also let `diff` compare directories.

```
diff ~directory1 ~directory2
```

Without any option, diffing 2 directories will tell you which files only exist in 1 directory and not the other, and which are common files. Files that are common in both directories are diffed to see if and how the file contents differ. If you also want to search into subdirectories add the `-r` option.

Basically this should not show any differences if a copy was done correctly.

Comment: I'm having issues with the first paragraph :) Is block size and "fragmentation overhead" taken into account when calculating file size on *any* filesystem? A small text file containing text "hello" will be reported as 5 bytes in size, despite the fact that on most filesystems it'll occupy the whole 512 byte sector (on FAT) or 4096 byte block (on ext4 by default).

Comment: @Sergey for small size files the count it probably done differently. Have a look at this: http://ols.fedoraproject.org/OLS/Reprints-2008/kumar-reprint.pdf It has some great insight into EXT.

Comment: The size nautilus reports is actual file size, not on disk size, so it does not take into account filesystem overhead.

Comment: Here is a working link for the kumar-rewind.pdf: https://web.archive.org/web/20120319051043/ols.fedoraproject.org/OLS/Reprints-2008/kumar-reprint.pdf