# Files sizes differs from windows to linux

Tags: 12.04, windows, files

Continuation of below question

[Why Same File Shows Different Sizes in Different Operating Systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341143/why-same-file-shows-different-sizes-in-different-operating-systems)

Can both the files sizes be made the same. Guide me on how dis can be achieved.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on whatever you missed in the original answer... they ARE exactly the same size.  The sizes are being displayed using different metrics.  The units they are counting are different.  In the post you linked in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341143/why-same-file-shows-different-sizes-in-different-operating-systems#comment435880_341152) the person answering even mentions how you can get the "du" command in linux to display using the same metric as windows is using which is actually a Kibibyte, Mebibyte, or Gibibyte depending on what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Mudit said different os uses different file structure. The different file structure which uses different the size of space for storaging files. The windows os uses NTFS partition and The linux os uses ext3 or ext4 partition. so you can find that the same file shows different sizes in different operating systems.

Comment: While technically this is correct... it does not account for the significant difference in the numbers in general.  In fact, in Windows when you look at "properties" for a file it will show an exact size in bytes as well as a size on disk (with filesystem overhead).

  They are being reported in different metrics (units of measurement).  In Windows they are counted in units of 10000000000 base 2 (1024 bytes = Kibibyte) and Linux is counting in 1000 base 10 (1000 bytes = Kilobyte).  If you actually look at only the Byte metric they should be the same.

Comment: Good job, thanks. As you said, i have try to check it. I using `du -b filename` command to get exact size. And it is the same size in windows. So you are right. I am sorry for the wrong answer. But i think that the size of file  and the size of file's space usage on disk are different。 right？