# Pasted file has more MB than the copied?

Tags: filesystem, files, transfer

Ok so I have ubuntu 15.10 installed on a USB and boot with it as my main OS on this computer.

The computer has 2 hard disks one connected to a SATA interface and one through USB too... none of them is associated in any way with the main OS I just mounted them to copy my personal folder (from windows users folder) from one disk to an other...

because I was bored I chose to copy the entire folder (with appdata etc) anyway the entire folder was 24 GB according to ubuntu with 81167 files so I copied  this folder from lets say drive A to drive B and in drive B 81065 files were copied (some authentication/certificate files in appdata couldnt be copied by ubuntu clicking on "details" shows that ubuntu cant copy "special files" anyway) though less files were copied the folder to the destination drive B is 24.2 GB (instead of being less than 24 or at least equal to that)

how come?

Comment: What file systems are in use on the two drives?

Comment: well both (source A and destination B) are NTFS and my linux usb stick running ubuntu is ext4

Answer (score 1):

Windows assumes that there are 1024 Bytes in a Kilobyte unit, and 1024 Kilobytes in a Megabyte unit. While Ubuntu assumes, a 1000 bytes constitute a Kilobyte (KB) unit, 1000 Kilobytes for a Megabyte (MB) and so on.

Windows is using the ‘binary prefix’, and Ubuntu or GNU/Linux, is using it in its ‘proper’ foam.

further read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341143/why-same-file-shows-different-sizes-in-different-operating-systems).

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with that because A) when this happens ubuntu uses the MiB unit instead of MB etc and B) both measurements (24GB from source and 24.2 from destination ) are made by ubuntu file manager since I used ubuntu to copy the folders no windows or other OS involved what so ever.  I right clicked on source folder and click on properties and I did the same to its clone on the destination drive and then had both resulting windows next to each other one said 24 GB the other 24.2GB...

Comment: I just hope that ubuntu doesnt have a bug or anything while transferring data from an nonlinux NTFS drive to and other nonlinux NTFS drive like corrupting/jittering the files or adding unnecessary data while doing the job