# File size is different in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: files, filesystem, filemanager

I am using windows and Ubuntu as dual boot, But File size is different in Windows and Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Which commands you have tried "ls -lh filename" or "du -skh filename"  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Same File Shows Different Sizes in Different Operating Systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341143/why-same-file-shows-different-sizes-in-different-operating-systems)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are confuse about is the different between `MB` and `MiB`.

Run the below command and pay attention to its output

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=100

Out: 100 MB, 95 MiB
```

It says 100 times read from `/dev/zero` each time `1,000,000` Bytes.

Now run this one:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1MiB count=100

Out: 105 MB, 100 MiB
```

This one says that read 100 times from `/dev/zero` each time `1,048,576` bytes.

You can use `ls` to get more familar with this concept:

```
ls -lh --block-size=MiB file
```

Or:

```
ls -lh --block-size=MB file
```

See the different?

`1 MB`  is equal to `0.953674 MiB`, it's just how your file managers are using different units.

SI standard units says that mega is equal to 10^6 = (1000000), however in computers we almost do everything in base of 2 (e.g 2^20 = 1048576); what should we call it? simply we can't call it mega cause it's close to that number; it's against the standard.

So to follow the standard we use another unit called mebibyte instead of megabyte, and 1 MiB is equal to 2^20 or 1,048,576 Byte.

---

Further reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte
http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html
https://tech.slashdot.org/story/01/12/23/1421225/megabytes-mb-or-mebibytes-mib